# Why does require react-native-icons fail?

Tags: react-native

I'm creating a tab bar in an ios app and I would like to try the react-native-icons.

I followed the steps on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/corymsmith/react-native-icons) and the section on Custom Tab Bar starts with:

```
var { TabBarIOS, } = require('react-native-icons');
```

I get the error below in the simulator.  How does it resolve the path for this module in the require statement?

I also noticed that libReactNativeIcons.a under 
Libraries -> ReactNativeIcons.xcodeproj -> Products is red and doesn't exist.

Suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Ensure that you have linked the library correctly. See the instructions here: https://github.com/corymsmith/react-native-icons#getting-started---ios

> ### Getting started - iOS
>
> > In XCode, in the project navigator right click Libraries ➜ Add Files to [your project's name]
> >
> > Go to node_modules ➜ react-native-icons➜ ios and add ReactNativeIcons.xcodeproj
> >     Add libReactNativeIcons.a (from 'Products' under ReactNativeIcons.xcodeproj) to your project's Build Phases ➜ Link Binary With Libraries phase
> >
> > Add the font files you want to use into the Copy Bundle Resources build phase of your project (click the '+' and click 'Add Other...' then choose the font files from node_modules/react-native-icons/ios/ReactNativeIcons/Libraries/FontAwesomeKit).
> >
> > Run your project (Cmd+R)

2. Include the module in your react-native application

Include the module using `{ Icon, } = require('react-native-icons');` and use it in your application:

```
<Icon
  name='ion|beer'
  size={40}
  color='#887700'
  style={styles.beer}
/>
```

Take a look at the example project here: https://github.com/corymsmith/react-native-icons/blob/master/Example/index.ios.js

**Edit**
To use it in your tab bar as well, try something like this:

```
var { Icon, TabBarIOS} = require('react-native-icons');
var TabBarItemIOS = TabBarIOS.Item;

[... and then inside your `<TabBarIOS>` ...]

<TabBarItemIOS
   name="home"
   iconName={'ion|ios-home-outline'}
   selectedIconName={'ion|ios-home'}
   title={''}
   badgeValue={'3'}
   iconSize={32}
   accessibilityLabel="Home Tab"
   selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'home'}
   onPress={() => {
     this.setState({
       selectedTab: 'home',
     });
   }}>
```

It might help to download and run the example application.